# Installing Zend Framework on Xampp and windows 7

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

I have worked on Zend-Framework on linux environment since last 6 months where i used to install the zend framework by simply creating a virtual host and in the corresponding virtual host i will change the path to the zend public folder.. In this way I installed zend framework on Linux (Ubuntu) but currently i have requirment to install to zend framework on windows 7 + xampp , i am not able to install this.. i stuck there...please help me to install zend on windows + xampp environment.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much the same as you have done under Linux. You will need to go in your Xampp install. There, you will have a `bin` folder (might be an other name) which will contain your apache folder. In that folder, dig deep enough to find the `httpd.conf` file.

In that file, search for the include of the `vhost.conf` files. It will probably be commented out with a `#` at the beginning of the line. Uncomment it. Take note of the path and find the vhost file (most likely in the extras folder).

In that file, you can define your vhost as you see fit.

Last step, go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and edit the `hosts` file. To edit it, you have to be admin (launch NotePad as admin through right clic menu > Execute as administrator). Add the name of the vhost you just created and make it point to your localhost ip address.

Restart Xampp, it should now find your freshly created vhost.

Comment: I have installed successfully on windows.. following are the best link i have ever found for zend framework installation , it helps me http://www.w3programmers.com/install-zend-framework-2-on-your-wamp-and-xampp-server/#comment-7765